# How to join two dataframes with many-to-many in the same group using pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, many-to-many

I want to merge two dataframes into one, but there are some duplicate values in the key, which is Item. It can't be achieved by using 'cross join' cuz it only uses "cross join" in the same group. Can someone share the thought to solve it? Thanks

For example:

dataframe1:

```
ID    Item    Price
1     apple     5
1     banana    3
1     lemon     2
2     apple     7
2     banana    4
2     lemon     4
```

dataframe2

```
Item     state
apple      TX
apple      CA
apple      NJ
banana     CA
lemon      NY
lemon      PA
```

Expected result:

```
ID    Item    Price   State
1     apple     5       TX
1     apple     5       NJ
1     apple     5       CA
1     banana    3       CA
1     lemon     2       NY
1     lemon     2       PA
2     apple     7       TX
2     apple     7       NJ
2     apple     7       CA
2     banana    4       CA
2     lemon     4       NY
2     lemon     4       PA
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Not really, I do know how to join two dataframes   It's not just using left, right or cross join tho.

Comment: I tried to set up the index as "Item" for two dataframes. Then, to merge with index by using "cross" way. Yet, it can't work still.

Comment: `df1.merge(df2,on='Item',how='outer')`?

Comment: Oops, alright. I made a mistake that the values in one of the column"item" starts with a capital character...  That's why it can't work....  seems like it's a stupid question smh...  what should I do for this post @AnuragDabas   Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```py
pd.merge(df1, df2).sort_values(by=['ID'])
```

output:

```
    ID    Item  Price state
0    1   apple      5    TX
1    1   apple      5    CA
2    1   apple      5    NJ
6    1  banana      3    CA
8    1   lemon      2    NY
9    1   lemon      2    PA
3    2   apple      7    TX
4    2   apple      7    CA
5    2   apple      7    NJ
7    2  banana      4    CA
10   2   lemon      4    NY
11   2   lemon      4    PA
```